# Converting image paths to uris

Tags: android, arrays, if-statement, uri, android-image

I am trying to convert the image paths of selected images in my grid view to uris, so that I can then pass those onto my photo editor, and edit from there.

```
                    if (cb.isChecked()) {
                    String paths = imagePaths.get(i);
                    Uri uri = Uri.parse(paths);
                    editImagesUri[count] = uri;
                    count++;
                }
```

That is my code where I am getting my NullPointerException, and I just can't seem to figure out what the problem is.

I have changed around the content in the if statement a few times so that it essentially does the same thing, but the error is still the same.

This is the value of paths:

```
imagePaths = new ArrayList<String>();
    imagePaths = getPathOfAllImages(getActivity());
```

This is the value of uri:

```
private static Uri[] editImagesUri;
```

getPathOfAllImages is a method I found on this website as an answer. Here is the code for it:

```
public static ArrayList<String> getPathOfAllImages(Activity activity) {
        ArrayList<String> absolutePathOfImageList = new ArrayList<String>();
        String absolutePathOfImage = null;
        String nameOfFile = null;
        String absolutePathOfFileWithoutFileName = null;
        Uri uri;
        Cursor cursor;
        int column_index;
        int column_displayname;
        int lastIndex;
        int counter = 0;
        // absolutePathOfImages.clear();


            uri = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

            String[] projection = { MediaColumns.DATA,
                    MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME };

            cursor = activity.managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
            column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaColumns.DATA);

            column_displayname = cursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);

            // cursor.moveToFirst();
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                // for(int i=0; i<cursor.getColumnCount();i++){
                // Log.i(TAG,cursor.getColumnName(i)+".....Data Present ...."+cursor.getString(i));
                // }
                // Log.i(TAG,"=====================================");

                absolutePathOfImage = cursor.getString(column_index);
                nameOfFile = cursor.getString(column_displayname);

                lastIndex = absolutePathOfImage.lastIndexOf(nameOfFile);

                lastIndex = lastIndex >= 0 ? lastIndex
                        : nameOfFile.length() - 1;

                absolutePathOfFileWithoutFileName = absolutePathOfImage
                        .substring(0, lastIndex);


                    if (absolutePathOfImage != null) {
                        absolutePathOfImageList.add(absolutePathOfImage);
                    }


            }


        // Log.i(TAG,"........Detected images for Grid....."
        // + absolutePathOfImageList);
        return absolutePathOfImageList;
    }
```

Comment: Which line does the error occur on? What is the value of paths? And uri?

Comment: The error occurs on the same line as the if-statement. And I added the extra info up top.

Comment: The error occurs on 'if (cb.isChecked())' ? Then make sure cb is set. Also, by value, I meant what is the actual value that those variables are getting set to after those lines run. Read up on debugging.

Comment: ohhhh. Well I have them set in for loops, and it pretty much crashes when it hits the first check mark. So I checked the second box on my screen, therefore i would be 1, and count would be 0. Cb is also set in the few lines above it.

Comment: since the problem is probably with `cb`, posting the code where you initialize it might help

Comment: I actually fixed that part of the code. I am now getting the error @ editImagesUri[count] = uri; I don't know what could be the problem though.